# Drain Hose - Reverse Water Pressure in Standby

Tags: water, drain, dishwasher, pump, condensate

I have 5 drain hoses from various appliances (dishwasher, laundry washer, AC condensate,
water softener, water filter) that all have the standard regulated air gap to a sink.

I imagine drain pumps on these appliances could create enough pressure to blow their drain
hoses completely clear of water, but in looking at a few examples, it seems that this is
never done.  In other words, it seems each of my 5 appliances leaves its hose full of
water (from the appliance's pump) to the highest hose point.

That heightened water then creates a reverse pressure when the pump is turned off (i.e.,
when the appliance goes into standby mode).  For example, my dishwasher needs to hold
off 3-feet-elevated water after the drain with some sort of drain seal.  A slight seal
leak would retake the water over days and potentially stink up my dishwasher.  Even if
the seal holds perfectly, I worry that the water left in the dishwasher's drain hose
could get stinky...I wonder if I'm misunderstanding this, so please correct me if I'm
wrong...maybe there is no real problem (stink or otherwise) from leaving still water
in these hoses for weeks.

Finally, my question:
Is any appliance, especially a dishwasher, designed instead to leave its drain hose empty?
Maybe a sump pump?

Comment: The pumps in these appliances pump water not air, so they will never blow their drain hoses  clear of water at all.

Comment: @brhans Ok. Seeing this actually led me to this question, so I did want to confirm that, thank you.  If it were easy to blow out (or manually empty) the hoses for standby, would there be any harm in that?  Generally, houses try to avoid standing water (especially for waste water with food/bacteria), so that's motivating me here, but it's mainly curiosity now.  It's also odd that none of my appliances (except for my Beckett CB151UL condensate pump) spec the maximum drain hose height - I'm curious exactly how high the average dishwasher drain can pump water.

Comment: The water at the end of a cleaning cycle shouldn't really be dirty though, it's just a rinse. And do you really go weeks between dishwasher runs? If so it'll get stinky due to dirty dishes sitting in it for weeks and the hose will be the least of your issues.